# mysql_query() returns returns true, but mysql_num_rows() and mysql_fetch_array() give "not a valid resource errors

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code in question:

From index.php:

```
require_once('includes/DbConnector.php');

// Create an object (instance) of the DbConnector
$connector = new DbConnector();

// Execute the query to retrieve articles
$query1 = "SELECT id, title FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5";
$result = $connector->query($query1);

echo "vardump1:";
var_dump($result);
echo "\n";

/*(!line 17!)*/ echo "Number of rows in the result of the query:".mysql_num_rows($result)."\n";
// Get an array containing the results.
// Loop for each item in that array


while ($row = $connector->fetchArray($result)){

echo '<p> <a href="viewArticle.php?id='.$row['id'].'">';
echo $row['title'];
echo '</a> </p>';
```

From dbconnector.php:

```
$settings = SystemComponent::getSettings();

// Get the main settings from the array we just loaded
$host = $settings['dbhost'];
$db = $settings['dbname'];
$user = $settings['dbusername'];
$pass = $settings['dbpassword'];

// Connect to the database
$this->link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
register_shutdown_function(array(&$this, 'close'));

} //end constructor

//*** Function: query, Purpose: Execute a database query ***
function query($query) {

echo "Query Statement: ".$query."\n";

$this->theQuery = $query;

return mysql_query($query, $this->link) or die(mysql_error());

}

//*** Function: fetchArray, Purpose: Get array of query results ***
function fetchArray($result) {

echo "<|";
var_dump($result);
echo "|> \n";

/*(!line 50!)*/$res= mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());

echo $res['id']."-".$res['title']."-".$res['imagelink']."-".$res['text'];

return $res;
}
```

Output:

```
Query Statement: SELECT id, title FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5 vardump1:bool(true) 
PHP Error Message

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /*path to*/index.php on line 17

Number of rows in the result of the query: <|bool(true) |>
```

PHP Error Message

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /*path to*/DbConnector.php on line 50
```

Comment: can you post your query string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698740/mysql-num-rows-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-resource)

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is in fallowing line:

```
return mysql_query($query, $this->link) or die(mysql_error())
```

it should have been written like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $this->link);
if(!$result) die(mysql_error());
return $result;
```

It is common in dynamic languages that `or` returns first `object` which evaluates to true, but in PHP the result of `X or Y` is always **true** or **false**.

Comment: I just realized that when I echoed the mysql_error()... thanks people!

Answer (score 0):

As you can learn from the manual, mysql_query return value type is not boolean but resource.
Something in your code converting it

Comment: i bet the link is valid and his db_select is failing?

Comment: mysql_db_select() gives bool(true) in var_dump, so it's not that.

Comment: @ Col. Shrapnel - what could convert query result to a boolean? I posted code for all the $result variable lifetime. BTW, query statement works in phpmyadmin and returns valid results.

Comment: @zlance4012 nobody question your query statement. I am talking of mysql_query function result

Answer (score 0):

Agree with above, you have an issue with your mysql_query.  It should never return True.  Either false or a resource.

Refactor :  mysql_query($query, $this->link) or die(mysql_error())

echo mysqlerror() after your query and see what the error message is.  You probably do not have a valid connection.

Comment: @zlance4012 refactor it from silly childish die() to proper trigger_error()

Comment: For example : $dbconn = mysql_pconnect($myhost, $myuser, $mypass); if (!$dbconn) trigger_error('Database connection failure', E_USER_ERROR);

When you use trigger_error, the error will be processed according to PHP's error handling routines.