# Account activation PHP

Tags: php, mysql, account-management

I created this account registration activation script of my own, I have checked it over again and again to find errors, I don't see a particular error...

The domain would be like this:

> http://domain.com/include/register.php?key=true&p=AfRWDCOWF0BO6KSb6UmNMf7d333gaBOB

Which comes from an email, when a user clicks it, they get redirected to this script:

```
if($_GET['key'] == true)
{
    $key = $_GET['p'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users
            WHERE user_key = '" . $key . "'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_affected_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE users
                SET user_key = '', user_active = '1'
                WHERE user_key = '" . $key . "'";

        $result = mysql_query(sql) or die(mysql_error());

        if($result)
        {
            $_SESSION['PROCESS'] = $lang['Account_activated'];
            header("Location: ../index.php");
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['ERROR'] = $lang['Key_error'];
            header("Location: ../index.php");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['ERROR'] = $lang['Invalid_key'];
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }
}
```

It doesn't even work at all, I looked in the database with the user with that key, it matches but it keeps coming up as an error which is extremely annoying me. The database is right, the table and column is right, nothing wrong with the database, it's the script that isn't working.

Help me out, guys.

Thanks :)

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is your friend. You should escape your parametrized attributes (for example attributes that come from a URL). In this case, your $key variable.

http://ar.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: I already know that, I have a function which is called safeClean() that has included functions to sanitize the data, but I removed it to make sure it wasn't it that was affecting, therefore it didn't and haven't used the previous code. The MySQL escaping is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change `$_GET['key'] == true` to `$_GET['key'] == "true"`
2. You do before this `if`, a successful `mysql_connect(...)` or `mysql_pconnect(...)` ?
3. Change `mysql_affected_rows($result);` to `mysql_num_rows($result);`. Affected you can use for `DELETE` or `UPDATE` *SQL statements*.
4. Before you second if was opened, add before you second `mysql_result(...)`, `mysql_free_result($result);` to free memory allocated to previous result.
5. `if($result)` change to `if(mysql_affected_rows($result));`. You can do that here.
6. After the `header(...);` function call's add a `return 0;` or `exit(0);` depends on your complete code logic.
7. You are using `$key` variable in *SQL statements*, to get your code more secure on **SQL Injection attacks** get change `$key = $_GET['p'];` to `$key = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']);`
8. I think your location in `header()` functions fails. In `header()` url address should be full like: http://www.example.com/somewhere/index.php
9. And check your `$_GET['p']` variable exists!! If this not exist and if `$_GET['key']` exists, you find all activated users. Then i think the setting user_key to '' is nessesary if you have user_activated marker.

Comment: Already tried with and without quotes. The MySQL connection is fine.

Comment: I know but this may don't work in future versions of php engine.

Comment: $_GET['key'] == true is actually evaluating if $_GET['key'] has any value..so you can call your script with key=false and it will still pass the validation..Although this doesn't solve the problem, its just a warning ;)

Comment: @Gonçalo Queirós: But that can be evaluated as that: convert to bool $_GET['key'] and compare values. That may be unpredicted result if $_GET['key'] == 0(int).

Comment: I updated it to your 3rd option, it says this: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sql' at line 1**

Comment: @Wayne: Sorry but in 3rd and in before statmets I don't modify your query and this is mysql error.

Comment: Don't use `addslashes()`; it can quote text wrong for MySQL. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: @staticsan: i know, but i can't find this function by the search form on php.net, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you shouldnt be using:

```
if(mysql_affected_rows($result) > 0)
```

You should be using mysql_num_rows()

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

"or" makes your statement `boolean` so $result gets a `True` instead of value returned by mysql_query()

```
echo 'Hello' or die('bye'); // outputs nothing, because result is True not 'Hello'

3 or die() == True; // true
3 or die() != 3; // true
```

**OR** is the same as **||** and it is *operator of logical statement*.

This will work:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result) die(mysql_error());
```

The same mistake was made a few hours ago: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009035)

---

Cases where OR can be used:

```
defined('FOO') or
    define('FOO', 'BAR');

mysql_connect(...) or die(...);

mysql_select_db( .... ) or die(...);

mysql_query('UPDATE ...') or die(...);

if(FOO or BAR) { ... }
```

Comment: But if first value in OR expression is true, next is not executed then if mysql_query result a variable is not a false this die() not execute never. This is good. This syntax is use everywhere and everywhere woking good.

Comment: At least don't be so ignorant and test even things you don't like.

Comment: I have always used "or" in this way and it is never problematic.

Comment: `BOOL or die()` will `die()` if `BOOL` is false.